# How do I remove git's MERGE_MSG?

Tags: git, merge, git-pull

I've tried a few things suggested, but nothing seems to remove it. This started occurring when I upgraded to Mountain Lion OS X. Anytime I do a `git pull`, it displays this annoying as heck empty editor with the title MERGE_MSG.

How do I prevent that from popping up *globally* across all my apps?

Comment: If that's happening often enough to be that annoying to you, that's likely a sign that you're doing too many merges resulting in an ugly history.

Comment: What if you're sharing work with other developers? Wouldn't that be inevitable?

Comment: Note that the intended behavior here is to open an editor and let the user type in a message. However this only works with nano etc and fails with sublime-text etc since the sublime process **immediately exits** if sublime is already open (I always keep it open)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can either pass `--no-edit` to `git pull`, or you can set the environment variable `GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT` to `no`.

From the [`git pull`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) documentation:

```
   --edit, --no-edit
       Invoke an editor before committing successful mechanical merge to
       further edit the auto-generated merge message, so that the user can
       explain and justify the merge. The --no-edit option can be used to
       accept the auto-generated message (this is generally discouraged).
       The --edit option is still useful if you are giving a draft message
       with the -m option from the command line and want to edit it in the
       editor.

       Older scripts may depend on the historical behaviour of not
       allowing the user to edit the merge log message. They will see an
       editor opened when they run git merge. To make it easier to adjust
       such scripts to the updated behaviour, the environment variable
       GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT can be set to no at the beginning of them.
```

Answer (score 4):

Git creates a merge commit here and wants you to add some words to the commit message.

Why a merge? A `git pull` is a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. The latter *might* result in the attempt to create a merge commit and this seems to happen for you.

There are several ways to avoid that. I would propose to let `git pull` trigger a rebase instead of a merge. That avoids additional merge commits and their messages. It also helps to keep the history linear. A `git pull --rebase` does this in one go (i.e. it is `git fetch` followed by a `git rebase`).

I configured that permanently with:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
```

Answer (score 0):

merge of remote branch to local gives more control then pull. the merge can be 'fast forward' (merge message is not needed), the merge message can be meaningful. Pull does not give you 'fast forward' option and always generate default merge message which is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.34 (Q4 2021) offer a more resilient experience, allowing for `.git/MERGE_MSG` to be automatically removed in two corner cases.:

Before, checking out all the paths from HEAD during the last conflicted step in "[`git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0ba5a0b3ba34270b2b57b75f4cce8454a7cc5eeb/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> and continuing would cause the step to be skipped (which is expected), but leaves `MERGE_MSG` file behind in `$GIT_DIR` and confuses the next "[`git commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0ba5a0b3ba34270b2b57b75f4cce8454a7cc5eeb/Documentation/git-commit.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))</sup>, which has been corrected with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021).

See [commit e5ee33e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5ee33e8551fa934862b8cbe50693f4841e7dace), [commit bed9b4e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bed9b4e3128af2c36645ba44fe19bf10af6d68ea), [commit 118ee5c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/118ee5c6135833a8fc015833dc3e471d9d31fbd8) (12 Aug 2021) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0ba5a0b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ba5a0b3ba34270b2b57b75f4cce8454a7cc5eeb), 03 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`rebase --continue`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5ee33e8551fa934862b8cbe50693f4841e7dace): remove `.git/MERGE_MSG`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Victor Gambier</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> If the user skips the final commit by removing all the changes from the index and worktree with '[`git restore`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e5ee33e8551fa934862b8cbe50693f4841e7dace/Documentation/git-restore.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore))</sup> (or read-tree) and then runs '[`git rebase --continue`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e5ee33e8551fa934862b8cbe50693f4841e7dace/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L241)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---continue))</sup> `.git/MERGE_MSG` is left behind.
> This will seed the commit message the next time the user commits which is not what we want to happen.

And also (still Git 2.34):

See [commit f2563c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2563c9ef3c028b5d4165df02fdfc0fcd613102d), [commit baf8ec8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/baf8ec8d3a0327307f79efd31d5717a0c91c4d8c), [commit 0c164ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c164ae7a65f811ef3fb3188c63cd157335463bb), [commit 2be6b6f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2be6b6f411136c6773a90d2cfdacf3cccb79d3e6) (20 Aug 2021) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9135259](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9135259b0387ce55cc9bd9671653fc33bb734b1e), 03 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`rebase -r`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/baf8ec8d3a0327307f79efd31d5717a0c91c4d8c): don't write .git/MERGE_MSG when fast-forwarding
>
> <sup>Reported-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> When fast-forwarding we do not create a new commit so `.git/MERGE_MSG` is not removed and can end up seeding the message of a commit made after the rebase has finished.
> Avoid writing `.git/MERGE_MSG` when we are fast-forwarding by writing the file after the fast-forward checks.
> Note that there are no changes to the fast-forward code, it is simply moved.
>
> Note that the way this change is implemented means we no longer write the author script when fast-forwarding either.
> I believe this is safe for the reasons below but it is a departure from what we do when fast-forwarding a non-merge commit.
> If we reword the merge then '[`git commit --amend`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/baf8ec8d3a0327307f79efd31d5717a0c91c4d8c/Documentation/git-commit.txt#L271)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---amend))</sup> will keep the authorship of the commit we're rewording as it ignores `GIT_AUTHOR_*` unless `--reset-author` is passed.
> It will also export the correct `GIT_AUTHOR_*` variables to any hooks and we already test the authorship of the reworded commit.
> If we are not rewording then we no longer call `spilt_ident()` which means we are no longer checking the commit author header looks sane.
> However this is what we already do when fast-forwarding non-merge commits in `skip_unnecessary_picks()` so I don't think we're breaking any promises by not checking the author here.